# Angular, 2 JSON endpoints loaded, 1 ng-repeat. How to replace 1 within the other?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

I have 2 endpoints (which I do not think they are related) from `jpholder`:

**`jpholder/tds`**

**`jpholder/us`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing for you to do would be, if you had a users table and a todos table in a database, to make a SELECT with JOINing on the tables and get the user name to come out as part of the todo list by referencing users to the todo userId.

Alternatively, if you're only using fixed JSON or javascript arrays, then you can do something like this:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="todo in todos ">
    <td>{{todo.userId}}</td>
    <td>{{::returnUserName(todo.userId)}}</td><!--Should give you the correct username.-->
    <td>{{todo.title}}</td>
    <td>{{todo.completed?'COMPLETED':'INCOMPLETE'}}</td>
    <td> <button type="button" ng-click="UpdateTodo($index, true)" class="btn btn-info">Update</button> </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

And then for the javascript make a $scope variable:

```
$scope.users = [{id: 1, name:'John Doe'},{id:2, name:'Jane Appleseed'}];
$scope.returnUserName = function(userID) {
   var i, len;
   for (len = $scope.users.length, i=0; i<len; ++i) {
      if($scope.users[i].id == userID) {
         return $scope.users[i].name;
      }
   }
   return 'No user found.'
}
```

Comment: I agree and I actually tought about it l like that, the only problem is that im getting these values from here https://github.com/typicode/jsonplaceholder , therefore, I have no access to the databnase as this is just a fake json api

Comment: Great, so then the provided function should work to give you the user name, no? Or were you looking for another result?

Comment: omg...it worked. dang you're the man. Please explain to me what you did. 

btw I changed 'no user found' to name and presto!

Comment: Well, I simply created a function which, when provided the userID, would loop through an array of users ($scope.users), and if the userID matched the id of one of the items it was looping through then return the user's name. And then, for the HTML, it's just calling the scope variable returnUserName with a parameter userID, and thus returns the correct name. Additionally, the :: placed in front of the function in the HTML makes the function run only once since I'm assuming userIDs won't be changing. You can remove it if you want.

Comment: I'm gonna have to disect that explanation. but great thanks. I found out that taking the :: makes the app load the user replacement action faster. If it leave it, it will not show any users if I do 2 refreshes. after 3 or 4 loads again.

Comment: That would make sense. Use :: only if you aren't going to update the value.